# Java - object can't store data

Tags: java

My dad and I narrowed it down to the object can't store the data. also, I'm new to java. The code is supposed to print in the console the first name, last name, grade, and grade average. I think the problem is in public double getCalcGraeAverage() but correct me if wrong, please.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class Student here.
 * 
 * @author XXXX
 * @version XXXX
 */
public class Student
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int gradeLevel;
    double gradeAverage;
    int totalAssignments;
    double totalPoints;

      /**
     * Create a new student with student's name, grade, and average
     */
    public Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, int newGradeLevel, double newGradeAverage)
    {
        firstName = newFirstName;
        lastName = newLastName;
        gradeLevel = newGradeLevel;
        gradeAverage = newGradeAverage = 0.0;
    }

      /**
     * Return the student's first name. 
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

      /**
     * Return the student's last name. 
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

      /**
     * Return the grade level of the student. 
     */
    public int getGradeLevel()
    {
        return gradeLevel;
    }

         /**
     * Calculates grade average. 
     */
    public double getCalcGradeAverage()
    {

       double gradeAverage = totalAssignments / totalPoints;
       return gradeAverage;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        Student student1 = new Student ("XXXX", "XXXX", 11, 0.0);

        System.out.println("The student's first name is: " + student1.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("The student's last name is: " + student1.getLastName());
        System.out.println("The student's grade level is: " + student1.getGradeLevel());

        System.out.println("Please enter the total assignment points the student has earned: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double totalAssignments  = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of assignments given: ");

        double totalpoints  = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(student1.getFirstName() + " " + student1.getLastName() +  " average grade is" + student1.getCalcGradeAverage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `Student` class to the question?

Comment: Are you doing anything with `totalAssignments` and `totalpoints` at all?

Comment: I'm not sure, also added the code.

Comment: What's the point of `gradeAverage = newGradeAverage = 0.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are :

1. creating a `Student student1` object
2. reading `totalAssignments`, `totalpoints` from `System.in`
3. calling `student1.getCalcGradeAverage()`

between steps 2 and 3 you have to set the fields `totalAssignments`, `totalpoints` of `student` to the values you read or they will retain their default values of zero. E.g.

```
student1.totalAssignments = totalAssignments;
student1.totalpoints = totalpoints;
```

Also, since `totalAssignments` is of type `int`, you probably want to read it as:

```
int totalAssignments  = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Alright, I changed TotalAssignments and TotalPoints to int but now I try to run it and reads java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero. so does this mean that as you said the values are staying in the zero value? If so what do I do to fix this?

Comment: Thank you.  So are you stating that I should update the varables totalAssignments to double and totalpoints to int of student.

Comment: Thank you.  So are you stating that I should update the varables totalAssignments to double and totalpoints to int of student.  Further, the gradeaverage would be int?

Comment: These variables should be int or double according to what physical values they are expected to contain. Judging by the name `totalAssignments` sounds like it should be an int. I recommend above in my answer that you should read it as an int because that's what it is in your Student class.

Comment: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero is thrown when you divide a number by zero. The computer cannot perform such an operation

Comment: Thank you, replacing the totalAssignments = with the student1.totalAssignments = was the answer I needed.

Comment: If you decide to make both variables to int you will encounter integer division that you may not be familiar with. E.g. with ints 5/2 results in 2. While with doubles 5.0/2.0 results in 2.5. It's up to you if you want these variables to be ints or doubles. i.e. it's a design decision

Answer (score 0):

When writing your code, you declare variables for the student class with class scope.

```
int totalAssignments;
double totalPoints;
```

those class scope variable are used in the method :getCalcGradeAverage()
 totalAssignments of Student and totalPoints of student are used in this method

When you create a new Student those variable are equals to zero because not affected by a value in your constructor.

in the main method when you writes :

```
Double totalAssignments  =
```

you declare a new variable named "totalAssignments" with a method scope.When the method ends, the variable reference goes away and there is no way to access that variable any longer.
you can consider that the variable decalred is not the same that the student variable: student.totalAssignments is always equals to zero because no value affected to him.

Then assuming that you can do that :

```
student1.totalAssignments  = input.nextInt();
student1.totalPoints  = input.nextDouble();
```